# Anime.js animation with React's higher order component

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, anime.js

I have a functional component which renders grid elements.I want to give Anime.js animation to that component by wrapping it with HOC.
The question is 'How i can implement it in correct way and how i can select desired target element from WrappedComponent ?'.

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import anime from 'animejs/lib/anime.es.js';

function withAnimation(WrappedComponent) {

    return class extends PureComponent {

        handleAnimation = () => {
            anime({
                targets: 'targets are in WrappedComponent',
                translateY: [-30, 0],
                easing: 'easeInOutQuad',
                duration: 2000,
            })
        }

        componentWillMount(){
            this.handleAnimation()
        }

        render() {
            return <WrappedComponent {...this.props}/>;
        }
    };
}


export default withAnimation;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) in the parent component and pass it to the wrapped one and use it as `targets` :

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import anime from "animejs/lib/anime.es.js";

function withAnimation(WrappedComponent) {
  return class extends PureComponent {
    constructor() {
      super();

      // create DOM reference
      this.target1 = React.createRef();
    }

    handleAnimation = () => {
      anime({
        targets: this.target1,
        translateY: [-30, 0],
        easing: "easeInOutQuad",
        duration: 2000
      });
    };

    componentWillMount() {
      this.handleAnimation();
    }

    setTarget = el => {
      this.target1 = el;
    };

    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent setTarget={this.setTarget} {...this.props} />;
    }
  };
}

const WrappedComponent = props => {
  return <div ref={el => props.setTarget(el)}>Animate me</div>;
};

export default withAnimation;
```

Comment: Okay thanks i discovered the problem and suddenly found that `componentWillMount()` can't show me the element ))

Comment: yes it won't show you the element because the comopnent is not mounted yet, you should use `componentDidMount` instead